# C++ ATL Outlook plugin does not load

Tags: c++, outlook-addin, email-attachments, atl

I have made an Outlook plugin for 64 bit version of Outlook 2013 using Visual Studio Community 2013. I want to work with attachments from mail when sending mails.
The plugin is not loaded by Outlook even though `LoadBehavior=3` in the registry and if I try to load it in Outlook, I get nothing.

So there is the beginning of the header of my class `CConnect`:

```
class ATL_NO_VTABLE CConnect :
public CComObjectRootEx<CComSingleThreadModel>,
public CComCoClass<CConnect, &CLSID_Connect>,
public IDispatchImpl<IConnect, &IID_IConnect, &LIBID_PluginOutlookLib, /*wMajor =*/ 1, /*wMinor =*/ 0>,
public IDispatchImpl<_IDTExtensibility2, &__uuidof(_IDTExtensibility2), &LIBID_AddInDesignerObjects, /* wMajor = */ 1>,
public IDispEventSimpleImpl < 1, CConnect, &__uuidof(Outlook::ItemEvents) >
{
public:
CConnect()
{
};
void __stdcall OnSend(IDispatch * Item, bool Cancel);

BEGIN_SINK_MAP(CConnect)
    SINK_ENTRY_INFO(1,__uuidof(Outlook::ItemEvents),0x0000F005,OnSend,&fiMailItemEvents)
END_SINK_MAP()

DECLARE_REGISTRY_RESOURCEID(IDR_CONNECT)

BEGIN_COM_MAP(CConnect)
    COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IConnect)
    COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(_IDTExtensibility2)
END_COM_MAP()
```

There is an entry in the registry for the plugin.

Does someone have a good idea how to to load the plugin successfully in Outlook?

If an attachment have a size bigger than msize I want to save it with `SaveAsFile()` and to proccess it.

What are the arguments of `Attachment::SaveAsFile()`  I didn't find them in the documentation and is there any method `Attachment::size()`?

Comment: 0
down vote
accept
 

I try to handle the ItemSend event.( I want to process my attachment when the user has clicked on send and before sending the mail). I think I forgot to put a call to DispEventAdvise in the OnConnection method but I don't know what will be the first argument of this function call.

Comment: The plugin now loads.it was only the entry in the registry that was not a the right place. Now I think there is a problem with my method OnSend because I don't go inside this method when I send a new message. if someone has a an idea... bests regards.

Comment: 0
down vote
accept
 

I have put a call to DispEventAdvise in the OnConnection method but OnSend hasn't been called. I don't know if the call to DispEventAdvise must be putted in another method....

Comment: 0
down vote
accept
 

in the SINK_MAP I have put 0x0000F002 because I want to handle the ItemSend event and not the Send event but my OnSend method hasn't been called.Can we really handle the ItemSend event ? Otherwise I don't know how to handle the Send event and I don't know if it would solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to handle the [Send](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff860969(v=office.15).aspx) or [ItemSend](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865076(v=office.15).aspx) event?

> What are the arguments of Attachment::SaveAsFile() I didn't find them in the documentation and is there any method Attachment::size()?

See the [SaveAsFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869359(v=office.15).aspx) method description in MSDN.

Also you may find the [Size](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866906(v=office.15).aspx) property of the Attachment class helpful.

Comment: my problem is solved.my handler of ItemSend is now called.I have put a DispEventAdvise((IDispatch*)m_app, &__uuidof(Outlook::ApplicationEvents)); in OnConnection